# looping through divs jquery

Tags: jquery, loops

I am grabbing an RSS feed.

One of the nodes, for each of the items, contains html (more than one div's worth as shown).

```
<item><node><div id="listing>content</div></node></item>
```

Multiply this xml code by n number of items and you have a lot of `<div id="listing">` and yes I know ID's are unique, I cannot control the feed. And I am listing each item.

I am pulling in this xml and transforming it on an XSLT stylesheet.

So `<div class="mydiv">for each xml item grab <div id="listing"> display the content here </div><div>` is what I am doing so I can list out all the items in the RSS.

XSL for each works fine for things like the title of each item etc, but the problem comes in because all the node divs have the same id="listing".

What I need to be able to do is take the content in each div id=listing from the feed and place it inside my own.

I would like to be able to iterate through all of the div id=listing and pull the content down to one of my divs.

Is this possible with jquery and if so I am unsure how to do that.

Any help (other than make the ID's unique) would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You posted a similar question earlier and do you understand why it was closed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16243323/loop-through-divs-and-write-to-corresponding-divs

Comment: you don't need to use jquery. You can use XPath for that in your xslt. `div` is just another XML element, so instead of iterating `\item\node` you iterate `\item\node\div`

Comment: pretty much i guess, hoping this one is a little more clear

Comment: @user1689274 We would like to see an attempt or an effort to solve the problem. We cannot write code for you, but can help you if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: xpath is only good for xml no? this would be a string within the node

Comment: if i knew what code to write i wouldnt need to ask....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user1689274 see fiddle jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/49QFH I don't agree with the html but the fiddle does exactly what you've asked – Chris Moutray 15 mins ago

@ChrisMoutray already posted an answer in your other question with the jQuery answer.

```
var $output = $('#mydiv');

$('div[id="hascontent"]').each(function (i,v) {
    $output.append($(this).html());
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEkWH/

I also posted a comment with a solution not involving jQuery, but instead using `XPath` to get exactly what you need from the RSS feed in your XSLT: iterate over `\item\node\div` instead of `\item\node`.

Comment: i would have tried it there, but you guys closed my question and gave me negative feedback....

Comment: this solution puts each of the divs into one div....i need to put them into their own

Comment: another solution: string replace `id="listing"` with empty string. problem solved :-)

Comment: the original solution by @ChrisMoutray does that: jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/49QFH